# Plotting a tree timeline (evolution history)

Tags: data-visualization, timelines

I am currently writing a literature review, and I'd like to be able to plot the evolution of some of the algorithms by plotting papers I've read, and their connections via citation as a horizontal tree, and have the x-axis correspond to publication date.

Here is an example of what I am looking for.
[image: Linux Distribution timeline]

### Questions

- What is this type of graph called?
- Are there existing tools to produce this type of graph?

Ideally, I'd like to achieve this in R, or using D3.js, but I am flexible.

Comment: The folks at StackOverflow or DataScience communities would be able to help you better.

Maybe you'd want to look at (http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/07/building-a-tree-diagram-in-d3-js/)

Comment: @Dawny33, "What is this type of graph called?" is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @gung Yeah, I have realized it. But, as the comment was helpful and cannot be edited, I preferred to leave it as is.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to plot the timeline on the horizontal axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as the question is perfectly on-topic here, as it deals with "Data Visualization", I would reproduce the comment as an answer, so that future viewers can be benefitted.

**What is this type of graph called?**

This graph is called as a `"Tree diagram"` and sometimes also called a `dendrogram`

**Are there existing tools to produce this type of graph?**

Yes, the tree diagram can be drawn in all the major data science tools.

Here is a [link to the tutorial](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/07/building-a-tree-diagram-in-d3-js/) for plotting the tree diagram in D3.js

In Python, the [pydot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot) package can be used. Here is a [link](https://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/) to a detailed tutorial.

Here is another [tutorial](http://gastonsanchez.com/blog/how-to/2012/10/03/Dendrograms.html) in R, which gives a step-by-step guide on various types of tree diagrams.

I would recommend going with D3 for the dendrograms, owing to better aesthetics, ease of code and flexibility.