# How do I represent divergence and merging of items on a timeline graph or tree?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a series of mergers and spinoffs that can be represent a timeseries graph or tree that will split and sometimes recombine over time.  I'm looking to understand what this type of graph might be called or if there's even a standard term and/or some possibilities of what tools might be utilized in such a visualization.  I've seen some similar graphs called dendrograms in [a very similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171715/plotting-a-tree-timeline-evolution-history) (and [another question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52785/graphic-timeline-generation-tool)), but I haven't run across the ability for a set of lines on a timeline to merge back into lines after they split.  Does this type of graph have a more technical name?  What tools are used for representing this kind of data?

Below is an small clip of a Linux timeline from this page demonstrating this particular feature.
[image: merging timeline]

Comment: Such a graph is simple enough to draw.  The challenge is to handle the non-planar graphs gracefully: you will need a mechanism for minimizing the inevitable crossings and a graphical means to represent them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A directed acyclic graph might be what you are looking for. Perhaps a Sankey diagram will help?